# Disable requestBody for custom action in API Platform

Tags: api-platform.com

I want to disable openapi's requestBody documentation for a custom POST route action where no parameters are.
For this I have tried to extend the openapi_context like this:

```
/*
 * @ApiResource(
 *     ...
 *     itemOperations={
 *         ...
 *         "post_clone" = {
 *             ...
 *             "openapi_context"={
 *                 "requestBody"=null
 *             }
 *         }
 *     }
 * )
 */
```

Setting the requestBody to `null` or `false` is the same as skipping the value and leads to the default documentation for POST routes.
Setting the requestBody to `{}` writes the empty object in the documentation, but what I need is that the key is skipped in the documentation.

Comment: I'm curious, what is the purpose of this route ?

Comment: Clone of the entity (and all dependent entities of a different type).

Comment: And how do you know what is the entity to clone ?

Comment: It's an itemOperation: "POST /api/foo/1"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going the wrong way to implement your `clone` operation. `POST` operations are [collection operations](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/operations/#operations), not item operation. Even if today you're able to declare a `POST` operation as an item operation, it is more likely a side effect of API-Platform, not the expected behaviour.

In order to respect API-Platform lifecyle, i suggest you to do the following:

**First**, declare your `clone` operation as a POST collection operation, using as [input DTO](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/dto/#using-data-transfer-objects-dtos) named `MyEntityCloneDto`:

```php
use App\Dto\MyEntityCloneDto;

/**
 * @ApiResource(
 *     collectionOperations={
 *          "get",
 *          "post",
 *          "clone" = {
 *              "method" = "post",
 *              "path" = "/my_entities/clone",
 *              "input" = MyEntityCloneDto::class,
 *          }
 *     }
 * )
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=MyEntityRepository::class)
 */
class MyEntity
```

**Then** create the input DTO:

```php
namespace App\Dto;

use App\Entity\MyEntity;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

class MyEntityCloneDto
{
    /**
     * The entity to clone.
     *
     * @Assert\NotNull()
     */
    public ?MyEntity $myEntity = null;
}
```

**Finally** create the `DataTransformer`:

```php
namespace App\DataTransformer;

use ApiPlatform\Core\DataTransformer\DataTransformerInterface;
use App\Entity\MyEntity;
use ApiPlatform\Core\Validator\ValidatorInterface;

class MyEntityCloner implements DataTransformerInterface
{
    private ValidatorInterface $validator;

    public function __construct(ValidatorInterface $validator)
    {
        $this->validator = $validator;
    }

    public function transform($object, string $to, array $context = [])
    {
        $this->validator->validate($object);
        return clone $object->myEntity; //add more logic if needed of course
    }

    public function supportsTransformation($data, string $to, array $context = []): bool
    {
        return MyEntity::class === $to;
    }
}
```

To clone `MyEntity` with ID 5:

```sh
curl --request POST \
    --header 'content-type: application/json' \
    --header 'accept: application/ld+json' \
    --data '{"myEntity": "/my_entities/5"}' \
    http://example.com/api/my_entities/clone
```

This way, the `OpenAPI` view displays the truth and your operation remains stable.

Note that if you need a `clone` operation on all your entities, it is possible to re-use the data transformer, since its method are not typed. But in order to make the `Serializer` works, you need one DTO per entity, because it needs to know the type of the entity to clone.

Comment: Oh yeah, sure now that you say it. The clone operation is just another method to create a new item. :-)
Thank you

Comment: This answer is making things more complex than they are. Just because API Platform uses certain philosophy it doesn't make sense to apply it blindly for every case.  Hooking into custom operation context is completely valid solution which is mentioned in other answers and involves minimal changes.

Answer (score 1):

Just add `'defaults' => ['_api_receive' => false]` to you custom operation:

```php
#[ApiResource(
    itemOperations: [
        'post_clone' => [
            ...
            'defaults' => ['_api_receive' => false],
            'openapi_context' => [
                'requestBody'=> ['required' => false, 'content' => []]
            ]
        ]
    ]
)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make an item_operation POST, with a specific controller, no problem.

To disable de requestBody in the swagguer doc:

```
"openapi_context" => [
   "requestBody"=> ["required" => false, "content" => []],
]
```